# Not able to override wgpicasa pro in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am trying to override wgpicasa pro component into joomla but its not working. What procedure applied by me, I explain here:

```
structure:
components/com_wgpicasapro/views/album/tmpl/default.php
components/com_wgpicasapro/views/contentalbum/tmpl/default.php
components/com_wgpicasapro/views/contentwgpicasapro/tmpl/default.php
components/com_wgpicasapro/views/wgpicasapro/tmpl/default.php

for overriding:
templates/use_template/html/com_wgpicasapro/contentalbum/default.php
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need template override for these files

```
components/com_wgpicasapro/views/album/tmpl/default.php
components/com_wgpicasapro/views/contentalbum/tmpl/default.php
components/com_wgpicasapro/views/contentwgpicasapro/tmpl/default.php
components/com_wgpicasapro/views/wgpicasapro/tmpl/default.php
```

As per Joomla docs you have to copy those files to these locations

```
templates/use_template/html/com_wgpicasapro/views/album/default.php
templates/use_template/html/com_wgpicasapro/views/contentalbum/default.php
templates/use_template/html/com_wgpicasapro/views/contentwgpicasapro/default.php
templates/use_template/html/com_wgpicasapro/views/wgpicasapro/default.php
```

Once the files are copied you can customise it the way you want.